# Wolfram Cloud Mathematica BarChart different to Mathematica (native)

Tags: wolfram-cloud, charts

I just experienced the following different behavior in Mathematica and same in the Cloud regarding BarChart. I want to visualize two lists of data, one with origin right, one with origin left:

```
data1 = {1, 5, 3, 6, 7}; data2 = {5, 4, 2, 6, 1};
```

In Mathematica

```
b1 = BarChart[data1, BarOrigin -> Right]
```

and

```
b2 = BarChart[data2, BarOrigin -> Right]
```

produces:

[image]

Doing the same in Wolfram Cloud the chart with origin right misses the Axeslabel on the x-Axis.

[image]

Any ideas why or (better) a workaround for the cloud?

Comment: I can't reproduce it, but I suspect `Rasterize[BarChart[...]]` may look correct.